# Is it possible to use JS Fetch with ViewState cross domain?

Tags: asp.net, fetch, viewstate

I'm using the fetch API to display a webpage inside of a floating widget. The page has a form on it that uses viewstate. It works fine if the widget is on the same domain as the page I'm fetching, but if I put the widget on a different domain, then I get an invalid viewstate error. I have tried several things to resolve the issue, but none work. Does anyone know if it's possible to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

No. If by your definition of `widget` you mean something like an `iframe` then this would cause issues regarding [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) if you are trying to manipulate data between the `parent frame` and `iframe`, it wouldn't if the domain was the same though due to the [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: There is absolutely no issue with viewstate in an iframe only when using the fetch API is there an issue cross domain.